# How to Test Android app on chinese tablets?

Tags: android, apk

Sorry to be cheap But I have a chinese Android 4.0.3 tab .I have no idea how to test my app on this device other than copying the apk file to the device and install it, It is very lengthy process . Is there any way I could directly run the app using apk Like other brand devices.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are installing manually or with ADB?

Comment: How are you installing your apk to your device?

Comment: if "adb devices" do not recognize your tablet, you should to try different adb versions. It helped me, just replaced adb in the sdk folder with older one.

Answer (score 1):

Using adb tools you can install your app directly to your android device,

```
adb install <aaa>.apk
```

but do this process you need configure adb tools in your envirnment and check your device manufacture sapport for that, configure adb
http://esausilva.com/2010/05/13/setting-up-adbusb-drivers-for-android-devices-in-linux-ubuntu/

check under USB Vendor IDs in above url to check your android manufacture support for that

Answer (score 0):

Aslong as it has USB driver support you can  debug direct to the device, however failing that, i dont see why you couldn't when you wish to test build to a 'Test APK's' folder then use a .bat to do the lengthy steps for you with regards to copying to the device.